# How to catch HttpResponseException in AngularJS service?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

In my WebAPI controller, I have a function that returns either a correct result or a HttpResponseException.

```
public async Task<SearchResult> Search([FromUri] SearchArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchResult searchResult = await _case.Search(args, true);

            string validationError = searchResult.Error;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationError))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = string.Format("Could not find the case. {0}", validationError)
                });
            }

            return searchResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = ex.Message
            });
        }
    }
```

It is used in angularjs service which calls this function using a http get request as below.

```
svc.Search = function (searchArgs) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = 'sci/case/search?';

        $http.get(sc.baseURL + url, { params: searchArgs }).
            then(function (r) {
                if (!r || !r.data) {
                    console.log('Error: No Data Returned');
                    deferred.reject('No Data Returned');
                }
                deferred.resolve(r.data);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
}
```

When there is a successful result, r.data contains the expected result. But when there is HttpResponseException thrown from the controller, I can't catch the ReasonPhrase. I need to format custom error messages in the controller and display them in UI. Is HttpResponseException appropriate to accomplish this? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw exception the execution flow gets interrupted and internal server error will be returned as result.you should handle error and return error message as the result.

I think you better define a class to represent `API` call result like this :

```
public class ApiCallResult {
  public ApiCallResult (){
        Succeeded = true;
  }
  public object Result {get;set;}
  public bool Succeeded{get;set;}
  public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

then :

```
public async Task<SearchResult> Search([FromUri] SearchArguments args)
    {
        var result = new ApiCallResult (); 
        try
        {

            SearchResult searchResult = await _case.Search(args, true);
            result.Result = searchResult;

            string validationError = searchResult.Error;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationError))
            {                    
                 result.Message = string.Format("Could not find the case");
                 result.Succeeded = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                 result.Message = ex.Message;
                 result.Succeeded = false;

        }

        return result;
    }
```

and inside view :

```
svc.Search = function (searchArgs) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = 'sci/case/search?';

        $http.get(sc.baseURL + url, { params: searchArgs }).
            then(function (r) {
                if (!r || !r.Succeeded) {
                    console.log('Error: No Data Returned');
                    deferred.reject('No Data Returned');
                }
                deferred.resolve(r.Result.data);
            }, function (r) {
                console.log('Error: ' + r.Message);
                deferred.reject(r.Message);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the `statusText` property value in the error callback. statusText property of the response object is a string value which has the status text of the response. `HttpResponseException` will set the `ReasonPhrase` value as the status text of the response.

```
 $http.get(sc.baseURL + url, { params: searchArgs }).
            then(function (r) {
                if (!r || !r.data) {
                    console.log('Error: No Data Returned');
                    deferred.reject('No Data Returned');
                }
                deferred.resolve(r.data);
            }, function (err) {
                var errMsg =  err.statusText;
                alert(errMsg);               
            });
```

Comment: I tried this but statusText gives me "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details." Thank you.

Comment: Do the detail contains "Internal Server Error" ?

Comment: It should return the reason phrase in the error text unless you have some custom error handling which is doing something else . See here http://imgur.com/a/ZGHXC

Comment: Custom errors are not Off. But I dont have any custom error handling either. The <customErrors> element is not present so I added it with mode=On but I have the same result.

Comment: do you have any OnException overridden method ?